# Flash message displaying on root view instead of intended view after postback

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I'm setting up a join (sign up) page, and I can't get flash messages to show up for some reason. When I send a postback with an empty email field, I should be getting the error message 'Please enter an email.' It doesn't show, and for some reason when I click the root page directly after posting, the error shows on the root page!

Code:

```
 view.on('post', function(next) {
    async.series([ 
        function (cb) {
            if (!req.body.email) {
                req.flash('error', 'Please enter an email.');
                return cb(true);
            }
            return cb();
        }
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next();
        }
    });
});

view.render('join');
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check source for join page if you are rendering the flash messages, if flash messages are not rendered, it will show up on next page you visit (where it is rendered).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up figuring out the problem. In my --  var keystone = require('keystone')  --   declaration, I spelled keystone with a capital K. Couldn't believe it! I figured it would have thrown an error well prior to the flash message issue if this was the case. Your answer is in essence correct though, if was the source on the join page that was indeed the issue. Thanks again.